# Android databinding list of propertyIds

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm looking at a new project that uses databinding and certain property changes are not handled. The problem is that I don't know what the propertyIds are that go with said changes.

I can't find the generated `BR` class to see a list of propertyIds. Is there a place where I can find these IDs and see which one(s) I need?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly but here is what I think you are asking. Binding generates BR class after you build a project. The BR class is like the R class generated by android. BR class will include the variables added in the XML and class level variables that have a `@Bindable` tag to it.

Comment: Yes so I know that much, but I can't find the `BR` class. Even Android Studio (annoyingly) marks the references as not found. CTRL+Clicking the variables also does nothing useful.